# Add script for a HTML class in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I´m add to my ASP.NET project a html audio player. I divided it with jquery in different classes that I can style it with css.
For the script call I use.

```
<script>
        $( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );
</script>
```

But if I use it in ASP.NET it doesn't work.

I add the scripts to a bundle.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/audioplayer").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/audioplayer.js"));
     }
}
```

And I add render the scripts at the bottom of the side.

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/audioplayer")
}
```

Now, if i debug the side, he only show me the normal  tag, without any design. They don't add my -tag with the function.

Maybe someone finds my fault or what I forgot that it will work?

Comment: Add @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/audioplayer") at the top of the site

Comment: @DenisWessels is correct, it your bundled js for audioplayer must be on top of your js code that declare .audioPlayer()

Comment: @DenisWessels he shows me still the normal audio elemen, i test the script tag with an alert line, now he use the script but I think he have problems with the "$( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } )" line.

Comment: Try adding the script references manually to the page instead of bundling,for starters

Comment: @DenisWessels i add ...
"@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/audioplayer.js")"
"@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"
now, but no way. Maybe he have a problem because the side is rendered with "@RenderBody()" ? I add the scripts in the RenderBody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working on my side.Please try this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

<link href="~/Content/audio.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://osvaldas.info/examples/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly/audioplayer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('audio').audioPlayer();
    });
</script>
<div style="width:300px;">
    <audio src="~/Music/song.mp3" preload="auto" controls autoplay loop></audio>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: audioplayer.js plugin]

Comment: I create a new empty side and add your code, but it doenst work. 
After it I try to make a new ASP.NET (MVC) project and add the code again bt wihtout any results.

Comment: Do you have a folder in your application called Music and a file in there called song.mp3?Copy the code as is from my example into your view

Comment: I suit the code for me. The folder and the css path.
When I use the scripts in normal html it´s work fine. I look for the code with the browser devolper tools, in ASP.NET I actually see the <audio> tag. With normal html I have on the same place a div called "audioplayer". 
He cant / dont use the script.